# C# Winforms resize DataGridView to fill width but with wrap mode to off (allow scroll if required)

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am quite a new to Winforms and recently I got a situation. My client prefer to have each record show as one line and want to use the slide bar if cell has larger content. Moreover, he also wants to stretch the width of "Name" column if total width of all columns is less than width of DataGridView.

I have already set RowsDefaultCellStyle.WrapMode and ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.WrapMode to false along with DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells. But it doesn't stretch "Name" column even though I set it manually.

Comment: Can you improve on the question? If possible put some picture, what is expected and what are you seeing?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the right idea, but there is a slight quirk with how Fill works.  Here is sample code that will almost do what you want, which it sounds like you pretty much already have:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.dataGridView1.RowsDefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.False;
    this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.False;
    this.dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;

    this.dataGridViewColumnName.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
    this.dataGridViewColumnName.MinimumWidth = 60;
}
```

The one catch here is that I set the MinimumWidth on the Name column, that's because there is no DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode like AllCellsFillRemaining.  If you don't set a MinimumWidth on a column set to Fill it may be resized down to a few pixels if all the other columns crowd it out.  To truly get the behavior you're after I believe you would need to override the auto size behavior.